# Reading From a TCP Socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server

I have clients sending a request of a very simple form: just the string `GET/PUT/INSERT/DELETE KEY <VALUE>` where value is optional depending on the selected keyword.

Keys and values can be arbitrarily sized.

I am implementing a server in C to service the requests however I think I am running into the issue that the read() system call reads some, but not all data.  That is, what the server read is only a subset of what the client sent.

How can I know when the entire message has been read?

Example Requests:
`INSERT KEYkeyKEYkeyKEY VALUEvalueVALUEvalueVALUE`

But the Server Might Read:
`INSERT KEYkeyKEYkeyKEY VALUEvalueVALUE`

How can I know the entire message has not yet been received and read?

Comment: If you specify that the client must end each string with a carriage return, or a NUL/zero byte, or some other well-defined character that both client and server agree means end-of-line, then your server can look for that character in its TCP input-stream and parse the preceding characters whenever it sees it.

Answer (score 5):

TCP does not provide any way. TCP is a stream oriented protocol, all it does is send a stream of bytes. Its up to you to create  wire protocol on top of that stream so that you can detect message boundaries.

Classic ways

- send a fixed size prefix with the size of the expected message
- use a self describing encoding (ber for example)
- send a delimiter - say 2 blank lines in a text protocol (common for older RFC protocols)

Comment: * send a delimiter like a (single) \n newline... nothing wrong with “older” rfc protocols, they rule the internet - http, for example

Comment: Plenty of *old* protocols still commonly in use (FTP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, HTTP,etc) that use CRLF-delimited lines/commands

Comment: @RemyLebeau and barny , did not mean to demean those protocols.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I know the entire message has not yet been received and read?

You need some *conventions* to know where messages are ending. You parse your input.

Answer (score 2):

just a small hint: you're experiencing a short-read. As mentioned before typically you would add a fixed-length header that contains the length of the message or parse the message's format (imagine receiving a JSON-formatted String). You could also switch to a message based protocol such as UDP or SCTP.

Also keep in mind that long-reads could also theoretically happen, i.e., you could read two commands with a single network read (or one command and half of another command).